# JQuery each() function not working DropDownList Change

Tags: jquery

I have a table populated from a selection from a dropdownlist. If the status of any of the items in the table is anything other than 'success', I want to disable a button on the page, otherwise I enable it. I have a change event handler with the following:

```
function enableButton() {
    $(".myButton").attr("disabled", true);
    $("td.tdStatus").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == "SUCCESS") {
            $("input.myButton").attr("disabled", false);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

$(function() {
    $("#myList").change(enableButton);
});
```

On the first selection of an item from the dropdown, I'm getting into the event handler but `$("td.tdStatus").each(function()` isn't finding anything. When I then make a subsequent change to the dropdownlist, the button gets `enabled`/`disabled` as I'd expect. Any ideas why the first change isn't working?

HTML is as follows:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td runat="server" id="tdName"><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
        <td class="tdStatus"><%# Eval("Status") %></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you setting the "each" to a variable that you're not using? You shouldn't need to do that. And remember that $(".myButton") will change all elements with that class.

Comment: Can you post the relevant piece of html for the script?

Comment: Thanks Alex, i'm guilty of a copy and paste mistake with the variable, no excuses for that! Thank for the class tip, have changed to input.myButton, I presume that is a better approach (ther eis only one element with that class as things stand)?

Comment: I think this is looking to be how the data is being loaded into the table. I stupidly excluded some code I thought was irrelvant but in the change event the data is loaded inside a tab, I think this is asynchronous so that when my each() is encountered the data hasn't been loaded. I put a test in to do the exact same check on click of a button and it works fine if I load the page, wait a second then click. I'll investigate how the data is being loaded to see if I can make it synchronous.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Just to give an update, the tab the data is loaded into has a function that is bound to the tabsload event:

$("#tabContent").bind('tabsload', tabLoaded);

Inside tabLoaded I put a call to the enableButton() function and that's got it working ok, with the data completely loaded before the function fires.

Thanks all for your help, apologies for missing out the key information in the original post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give an update, the tab the data is loaded into has a function that is bound to the tabsload event:

$("#tabContent").bind('tabsload', tabLoaded);

Inside tabLoaded I put a call to the enableButton() function and that's got it working ok, with the data completely loaded before the function fires. Thanks all for your help, apologies for missing out the key information in the original post!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
function enableButton() {
    $(".myButton").attr("disabled", true);
    var x = $("td").find(".tdStatus", function() {
        if ($(this).text() == "SUCCESS") {
            $(".myButton").removeAttr("disabled");
            return false;
        }
    });
}

$(function() {
    $("#myList").change(enableButton);
});
```

I think that should work

Try this with .text() and .val() Im not sure which one should work

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that doesn't appear to work - I'm not getting the button enabled on any change of the dropdown now...

Comment: i'm sure text() is right. val() would be for input elements and this one is a table cell

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the disabled attribute altogether.

```
$(".myButton").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Presence of a disabled attribute no matter what the value will result in the control being disabled i.e.

**Disabled**

```
<input type="button" disabled="true" />
```

**Still disabled**

```
<input type="button" disabled="false" />
```

**Enabled**

```
<input type="button" />
```

Comment: No luck I'm afraid, it just doesn't seem to be getting into the each function at all

Comment: @RichardB Reverse the changes from the previous question perhaps

Comment: @RichardB Change selector from $("td.tdStatus") to $(".tdStatus")

Comment: Shouldnt this be just $(".myButton").removeAttr("disabled")

Answer (score 1):

A few more suggestions:

Have you tried using just .tdStatus instead of td.tdStatus?

Maybe you need to call the children of the td if your framework is creating divs for your entries?

```
function enableButton() {
    $(".myButton").attr("disabled", true);
    $("td.tdStatus").children().each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == "SUCCESS") {
            $("input.myButton").attr("disabled", false);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Try using alert() in the each method to see what is being returned

```
function enableButton() {
    $(".myButton").attr("disabled", true);
    $("td.tdStatus").children().each(function() {
        alert(jQuery(this).text());
    });
}
```